# facebook share fb-event with webdialog (on iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, share

Hi I have the following problem.
If I share an facebook event url (like https://www.facebook.com/events/) from an iOS app I have two possibillities:
(1) iOS facebook app is installed
(2) iOS facebook app is not installed

I case 1 everything works just fine. The facebook app fetches the event information, shows up a right preview and also the post on the facebook wall is right.
In case 2 I use the FBWebDialods class and it shows up a preview without the picutre and also the post on the facebook wall is just text. No image and no attend button.

Has somebody an idea of how I can get the same resulting post on the facebook wall in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

i get the response from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/:

```
// Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/"];
params.name = @"Sharing Tutorial";
params.caption = @"Build great social apps and get more installs.";
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png"];
params.description = @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.";

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
  // Present the share dialog
} else {
  // Present the feed dialog
}
```

and in Present the share dialog you add :

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                 name:params.name
                              caption:params.caption
                          description:params.description
                              picture:params.picture
                          clientState:nil
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                if(error) {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                } else {
                                  // Success
                                  NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                }
                              }];
```

i hope this help you

Comment: Like I wrote in my question I already use this switch between share and feed dialog. And if the facebook app is installed everything works fine with the share dialog. My question was how to use the feed dialog with the same result (picture, share button) while sharing a facebook event.